# How to define View Model from existing Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to know how do I define the viewmodel from below class.

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasCompleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeadLine { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
}
```

From above model, only Id, Name, HasCompleted and Deadline fields would displayed to the user. Otherwise fields CreatedDate and LastModified fields would be handled internally.

Initially the database table will be created with all the aforementioned fields. But, as mentioned, in order to avoid over posting attacks, I have created a view model with all the required fields. Now, the structure looked as below.

```
public class TestModel
{
    public TestVM testVM { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
} 
public class TestVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasCompleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeadLine { get; set; }
}
```

If would still like to maintain a single database table and make CRUD operations. But, I have a roadblock here in below action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(TestVM item)
    {            
        //Once the values are bound to TestVM. How do I get the instance of the TestModel to update the LastModified property here??
    }
```

Could someone please advise ?

Regards,
Ram

Comment: Could someone please advise on this ? Its very urgent..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove TestViewModel from TestModel class.

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasCompleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeadLine { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
}

public class TestViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasCompleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeadLine { get; set; }
} 

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(TestViewModel item)
{            
    var testModel = new TestModel 
    {
        Name = item.Name,
        HasCompleted = item.HasCompleted,
        DeadLine  = item.DeadLine 
    };

   //testModel.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

You can also use [Bind Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for prevent Binding `CreatedDate` and `LastModified` fields:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude("CreatedDate", "LastModified"))]TestModel item)
{            
}
```